# Start golang on the server

Tags: go

I created a tiny Go program on my computer:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Using the Terminal on Mac:

```
$ cd $HOME/go/src/hello
$ ./hello
```

The server is starting. And using Safari:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

I get "Hi there, I love hello!"

So far so good. But my challenge is to put this binary on the server and run the same.

**On the server**

Debian 8 using webmin creating a folder in root Go and put the binary in this folder

```
[root@server ~]# cd /go/
[root@server go]# ./hello
sh: 1: ./hello: Permission denied
[root@server go]#
```

The permissions for the Go folder and hello binary are 0644. AFAIK, the same as most files.

How do I deploy the Golang to the server and start the golang on the server? Lots of documentations on previous step, but I found none on the server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you'll need to use cross-compiling.

When you launch `go build -o hello .` on the mac, it's building a binary for you Mac.

But for running it on linux, you need to use cross-compilation: `GOOS=linux go build -o hello .`. It will build the binary for your server.

You can read this article from Dave Cheney: https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5

Comment: How important is the GOARCG=amd64 in the build process?

Comment: Hi there, I love hello! GOOS=linux and chmode 755 did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, GOARCH is for the architecture of your computer. For instance you can set GOARCH=amd64 in order to compile for an x64 computer.

I'm glad to see that it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to folder where your code located, and type in terminal `GOOS=linux GOARCG=amd64 go build` after it golang wiil create file for you, upload it on server and type `chmod +x your_file_name` after it run it using `./your_file_name`

Answer (score 1):

`Permission denied` usually points to a missing executable permission on the file.

The hello binary should have `755` or `700` on it (the former making it executable for everyone, the latter only for your user).

Run

```
chmod 755 ~/go/hello
```

or alternatively

```
chmod -R +x ~/go
```

The first sets explicit permission bits on just the server executable file, the second adds just the executable permission bit on the whole directory, as well as all contained files (and subdirectories). (Directories usually also have the `x`-Bit set, otherwise you wouldn't be able to list it's contents)